# How do I specify the root of the server when I ftp?

Tags: ftp

I am using c# in .NET 2.0. I HAVE to send the file to the C drive on the server. Is this the defaut? IE, would this go to the C drive?

ftp://myhost/test.txt

Answer (score 2):

The FTP root is determined by the configuration of the FTP server. It generally isn't the root directory of the system drive though.

Answer (score 0):

No, that would go to the home directory of the anonymous user.  If you were logged in, it would go to your home directory, I think.  Depends on the FTP server you're running; if it's a C:, IIS?

Answer (score 0):

It depends almost entirely on how the ftp server is configured on the destination server.  You should specify the path that is configured to correspond to the c:\ drive...